# Dspace importer can't find the collections

Tags: import, repository, dspace

I try to import from file system in dspace 6.3, and i cant define target collection by collection file.

I created a file structure for Simple Archive Format and i have a collection file with this content:
dtk/13

I tried to import by this command:
root@dspace:/dspace/bin# ./dspace import --add --eperson=myusername.hu --source=/tananyag/feltoltesre_var/archive_directory  --mapfile=mapfile141

No collections given. Assuming 'collections' file inside item directory

Adding items from directory: /tananyag/feltoltesre_var/archive_directory
Generating mapfile: mapfile141
Processing collections file: collections
Cannot resolve dtk/13 to a collection. Skipping.
Started: 1541766694907
Ended: 1541766697583
Elapsed time: 2 secs (2676 msecs)

But if i try the command with parameter, it works:
--collection=dtk/13
Destination collections:
Owning  Collection: újkollekcijó

It means the collection is available, why cant find it the importer in first case?
(I will have to import more thousand of items, and i cant create unique command for all of them)

Content of collection file (the handle of owning collection): 
dtk/13

Content of content file:
1.pdf
2.pdf

Comment: Consider adding the following information to this question: (1)list the contents of a couple files you are trying to add (2)show the content of your collections file (3)include output from the command that is not working as you expect.

Comment: Hi, there are the contents and the output:
Processing collections file: collections
Cannot resolve dtk/13 to a collection. Skipping.

The collection is availaible. If it weren't, the another command could not find it too.